# How do I define the password rules for Identity in ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 (vNext)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

The default Identity provider provided in ASP.NET 5 has very strict password rules by default, requiring a lower case character, an upper case character, a non-alphanumeric character, and a number. I am looking for a way to change the password requirements for the provider.

Previously in ASP.NET 4, the provider could be configured via the Web.config XML file, as [previously answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678454/how-do-i-define-the-password-rules-for-the-asp-net-membership-provider). However ASP.NET 5 uses the new code based configuration pattern and it is unclear how to configure the identity.

How can I change the password requirements for my application?

Comment: If you'd like to deep dive into password requirements (and you probably should), NIST (a standards board) has recently come out with new password guidelines. See a summary article here: https://www.passwordping.com/surprising-new-password-guidelines-nist/ And the full NIST Standard publication here. Refer to section 5.1.1.2: https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html#sec3

Answer (score 157, accepted):

I actually ended up figuring this out, it turns out you need to supply AddDefaultIdentity with a suitable lambda expression that configures the IdentityOptions it provides. This is done inside the ConfigureServices method within the Startup class, like so:

```
public class Startup {
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

        // Add Identity services to the services container.
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationIdentityDbContext, ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(Configuration,
            o => {
                o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                o.Password.RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false;
                o.Password.RequiredLength = 7;
            });
    }
}
```

**Update 2:**

The above was true in the beta1 versions of the framework, in the latest <s>rc1</s> beta5 it has changed slightly to:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(o => {
    // configure identity options
    o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationIdentityDbContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: Yep or you can just directly call services.ConfigureIdentity(o => { });

Comment: Nice! Do you think it's possible via the `config.json` file?

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde I just tried. Did not work. json below.

 "Identity": {
        "Password": {
            "RequireDigit": "false",
            "RequireLowercase": "false",
            "RequiredLength": "5",
            "RequireUppercase": "false",
            "RequireNonLetterOrDigit": "false"
        }
    }

Comment: From what I'm learning about MVC 6 I think that it's up to the programmer to *make* thinks configurable by reading it explicitly from config in the startup of the app.

Comment: Also have a look at this solution to set options after initialization: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30942723/1507481

Comment: I wonder why they aren't using the `services.Configure<PasswordOptions>(options =>` pattern... Maybe in RC2? I just tried using it, blatantly ignores it.

Comment: Wasn't it better if we change them in ApplicationUser class by changing Attributes of password property (like other logic rules)?

Comment: +1 for turning off the constraints. To back you up on this, the top websites and gov authorities have got rid of such constraints, the main reason - if it's not random, it's guessable (means hackable) and the only way to make it random is by using Password managers, which can't be enforced ATM. 
See the [Authentication Guidance for the Modern Era](https://www.troyhunt.com/passwords-evolved-authentication-guidance-for-the-modern-era/) and [Minimum Password Lengths by the World's Top Sites](https://www.troyhunt.com/how-long-is-long-enough-minimum-password-lengths-by-the-worlds-top-sites/)

Answer (score 30):

If you have set up a new Web project with `Individual User Accounts` go to:

```
App_Start -> IdentityConfig.cs
```

There you can edit the following defaults:

```
manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
{
    RequiredLength = 6,
    RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
    RequireDigit = true,
    RequireLowercase = true,
    RequireUppercase = true,
};
```

Answer (score 11):

in startup.cs:

```
   services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(x =>
        {
            x.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            x.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            x.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            x.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: This is the answer for Core 2.0. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like a lot of hassle to disable those things. Is there anyway to just disable the validation altogether at once? I mean, I do not want to enforce anything, and let the user choose the password on his own. If he gets hacked because he chose a dumb password like "1234", it is his problem.

Answer (score 8):

What I wanted to do was to customize the password rule so that it should contain  characters from **at least 2 of the following groups: lower case, upper case, digits and special symbols**.

This is not something that I could do by just changing PasswordValidator options:

```
manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
{
    RequiredLength = 6,
    RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
    RequireDigit = false,
    RequireLowercase = false,
    RequireUppercase = false,
 };
```

So instead I created a custom validator by extending IIdentityValidator...

First, create a new file CustomPasswordValidator.cs in your Extensions folder:

```
public class CustomPasswordValidator : IIdentityValidator<string>
{
    public int RequiredLength { get; set; }
    public CustomPasswordValidator(int length) {
        RequiredLength = length;
    }

    /* 
     * logic to validate password: I am using regex to count how many 
     * types of characters exists in the password
     */
    public Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(string password) {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(password) || password.Length < RequiredLength)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Failed(
                $"Password should be at least {RequiredLength} characters"));
        }

        int counter = 0;
        List<string> patterns = new List<string>();
        patterns.Add(@"[a-z]");                                          // lowercase
        patterns.Add(@"[A-Z]");                                          // uppercase
        patterns.Add(@"[0-9]");                                          // digits
        // don't forget to include white space in special symbols
        patterns.Add(@"[!@#$%^&*\(\)_\+\-\={}<>,\.\|""'~`:;\\?\/\[\] ]"); // special symbols

        // count type of different chars in password
        foreach (string p in patterns)
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(password, p))
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }

        if (counter < 2)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Failed(
                "Please use characters from at least two of these groups: lowercase, uppercase, digits and special symbols"));
        }

        return Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Success);
    }
}
```

Then go to IdentityConfig.cs, and initialize it in Create method:

```
manager.PasswordValidator = new CustomPasswordValidator(8 /*min length*/);
        /*
        // You don't need this anymore
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };
        */
```

See [my tutorial](https://medium.com/@bahreinihooman/how-to-define-custom-password-rules-in-asp-net-mvc-e7754be80fba) for more details.

Comment: I feel like this is the best solution for the user. This allows a reasonable level of security with giving the user flexibility. Rather than turning on or off certain restrictions, this allows the user to pick what they want with their password.