# How to change PasswordValidator in MVC6 or AspNet Core or IdentityCore

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In the Asp.Net MVC 5 using Identity, was possible to do the following:

```
 manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
            {
                RequiredLength = 6,
                RequireLowercase = true,
                RequireDigit = false,
                RequireUppercase = false
            };
```

How to change the same configuration in MVC 6?

I see that can be in ConfigurationServices method in the segment:

```
 services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
         .AddPasswordValidator<>()
```

But I could not use.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### The Solution Beta6

In the `Startup.cs` write the code:

```
          services.ConfigureIdentity(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            });
```

### Update Beta8 and RC1

```
            // Add Identity services to the services container.
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
               {
                   options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                   options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                   options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                   options.Password.RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false;
                   options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
               })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

### Update RC2

```
            // Add Identity services to the services container.
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
               {
                   options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                   options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                   options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                   options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric= false;
                   options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
               })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: In RC2, 'RequireNonLetterOrDigit' needs to be 'RequireNonAlphanumeric', just as a heads up.

Comment: +1 for turning off the constraints. To back you up on this, the top websites and gov authorities have got rid of such constraints, the main reason - if it's not random, it's guessable (means hackable) and the only way to make it random is by using Password managers, which can't be enforced ATM. 
See more details on that in the [Authentication Guidance for the Modern Era](https://www.troyhunt.com/passwords-evolved-authentication-guidance-for-the-modern-era/).